# how can I plot values with big variance using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The values of Y are like `[0, 2, 38, 47, 123, 234, 1003, 100004, 50000003, 1000000004]`

The figure I want to get is just as following:

[image: logplot]

Answer (score 4):

From the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html)

```
# log y axis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.01, 20.0, 0.01)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.semilogy(t, np.exp(-t/5.0))
plt.title('semilogy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

So use `plt.semilogy()`. If you want a X-axis with a log-scale, use `plt.semilogx()`. For both axis on a log-scale, use `plt.loglog()`.

Comment: Although the OP only explicitly asks about the y-values, the wanted figure clearly has a logged x-axis as well.  Maybe the OP forgot this?